# How can I select the right ListBox Item automatically when I press the Button in the Item I want to Check to delete this Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

So I got in WPF an ListBox where I  got an Button in my ListBoxItem through an DataTemplate. Im adding that Button Like this to my Item:

```
 <ListBox Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="15,20,10,15" MinHeight="25" Name="tbxFiles"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <TextBlock x:Name="ListText" Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="1"  Content="TF"  />
                                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="2"  Content="AF" />
                                            <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Text="Periode"  />
                                            <Button Grid.Column="4"  Click="RemoveMark_Click"  Content="Delete" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>
                </ListBox>
```

Every ListBox Item that gonna be created hass an deleteButton now and when I press this Button, this Code gonna be startet to Delete this Item:

```
        PeriodeCombo.Items.Clear();
        string required = tbxFiles.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);

         required = tbxFiles.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().Distinct()
                         .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);

         required = tbxFiles.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().Distinct()
                          .Aggregate((a, b) => a + ";" + b);

        string[] words = required.Split(';');
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            temp1.Add(word);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < temp1.Count; i++)
        {
            path.Remove(temp1[i]);
        }

            path.Remove(required);
        tbxFiles.Items.Remove(tbxFiles.SelectedItem);

        while (tbxFiles.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            tbxFiles.Items.Remove(tbxFiles.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
```

And this Code remove only these item I clicked on that they are checked. But what I want to do now is that I can delete the Items without selecting by clicking the delete Button in that the Item are. So That when I click the delete button the Item gonna get deletet without to click on that item. How did I kneed to change my Code to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `RemoveMark_Click` the first argument (typically called `sender` and of type `object`) should by the `Button` you clicked on, and its DataContext should be your collection item to remove.

So change RemoveMark_Click to sth like:

```
void RemoveMark_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArg args)
{
   //TODO add null checks a/o exception handling
   var uiElement = (Button)sender;
   var dataItem = uiElement.DataContext;

   tbxFiles.Items.Remove(dataItem);
}
```

Generally spoken, for a button, it is more common and good practice to use a Command to execute the desired action, because then you can put the magic in the ViewModel.
Also, in order to have a special layout for a listboxitem setting the datatemplate a/o the itemcontainerstyle of the listbox will typically suffice, you don't *need* to override the control template, but of course you can and it will work.

Comment: He doesnt know "collection.Remove"

Comment: maybe you need to add a using to the top of the cs file: `using System.Collections;`

Comment: i already got this using, the error message is: "ICollection has no definition for Remove"

Comment: Stupid me, change `ICollection` to `IList` ( i also edit my post...)

Comment: So I tried this now but when I click on delete, is the Programm crashing at this point " collection.Remove(dataItem)" with the error "The object reference was not set to an object instance"

Comment: Be aware that ItemsSource is not used by OP. They add directly to Items.

Comment: @Que Did you also cast to `Button` (not ListBoxItem)? I had an error in my post's first version here too... ;) What is the type of the viewmodel collection 'Items'

Comment: @Clemens but there's a binding `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` ...

Comment: It's there because in some other answer they were advised to add it, but they did not also add a view model. ItemsSource is just null. And the Binding is obviously pointless.

Comment: @lidqy   i dont know if I cast to Button i just got this code what I postet for that

Comment: @Clemens okay I see, you refer to previous posts. Then okay, he should remove that dataItem from the listbox Items collection.

Comment: @Que my last shot:
drop the last too lines (with 'collection' ) and replace them by
`tbxFiles.Items.Remove(dataItem);`

Comment: @lidqy I was not referring to any specific previous post. It is obvious from the question here that OP has no view model. They just have the useless Binding for no reason.